# CDec in Access SQL is not behaving the same as when used from Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) the syntax to convert a number to decimal in VBA is

```
CDec(expression)
```

I often use conversion function in access SQL as well.  eg Clng, Cint etc...

However when I use CDec  I sometime get this error

```
Compile error:Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

Consider:

In the immediate window

```
? cdec(round(0.00023,4))
0.0002 

? CDec(Round(0.12345678+0.00000001,6))
0.123457 

? CDec(Round(0.12345679,6))
0.123457 

? CDec(Round(0.12345679,6),10)
This gives the above error  (ie as expected as no parameter is allowed)
```

In a SQL query column

```
CDec(Round(0.12345678,6))
This gives the above error.

CDec(Round(0.12345678,6),2)
This WORKS and give the answer 0.     What does the parameter do!?

CDec(Round(0.12345678,6),2,1)
This gives the above error.
```

I guess when a function is called from access SQL it is using different code to the one used by VBA.  However, I'm stuck and don't understand.

Help!

I'm using MS Access 2013:  Build: 15.0.4727.1003  32bit

Harvey

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't noticed (or been hit) by this before. Perhaps you should just refrain from using CDec in SQL ...

Comment: I have used Cdbl instead, but as I'm dealing with data that has 6  decimal places, will this be accurate enough?

Comment: Doubles are accurate "as stored" and if only positive and (later) only added. Where bit errors may occur is when you subtract. If you numbers aren't too large, you could also scale using a factor of 100 and use Currency which handles four decimals with no errors.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug (a free login may be required): [Office 16 Bug Bash - July 15 ](https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=6031612&trk_event=search_ac&trk_model=group&trk_len=19&trk_pos=0)

Comment: I thought this would be classed as a bug...  Thanks for the suggestions I've sorted it out now... thanks.

Comment: How did you sort it out, please?

Comment: I stopped using CDec!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dennis Wilmar* of MS tells, that this is a confirmed bug from Access 2003 - not up to be removed:

[Error message when you use the CDec() function in an Access query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/225931)

The suggested work-around is to wrap CDec in a custom function:

```
Function NewCDec(MyVal)
   NewCDec = CDec(MyVal)
End Function
```